# How can I input to a pandas dataframe with live streaming?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have streaming data that is output in real time from a Python file.
I want to input this to a pandas dataframe in real time.
The file that outputs streaming data in real time is JAKMain.py.

The code output from the JAKMain.py file is as follows.

---

```
while True:
     time. sleep(3)
     result = api_con.AWS10000()
     print(time. strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
     for i in range(100):
         if i > 100:
             continue
         print(result['Data'] [i], end="")
```

---

In the JAKMain.py file, data in the following format is output.

```
{'DDDD': 'AAAAA'}{'DDDD': 'TTTT'}{'DDDD': 'JJJ'}{'DDDD': 'HHHH'}{'DDDD': 'DFEIUUH'}.......SKIP.......{'DDDD': 'VVV'}
```

Output 100 dictionaries to output 1.

It is printed every 3 seconds.

The output data is the updated data every time.

I want to input this output data into a Pandas DataFrame. In real time.

---

In a Pandas DataFrame , I want the data to appear in real time as shown below.

[image]

---

So I am writing the code as below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from JAKMain import *
```

But the real-time streaming data output from the python file.

Lectures or sources for Pandas DataFrame processing in real time,

Can't find it.

There is only processing the saved file.

---

To pass the output of JAKMain.py to DataFrame,
I think you can change your code like below.

```
while True:
     time. sleep(3)
     result = api_con.AWS10000()
     print(time. strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
     for i in range(100):
         if i > 100:
             continue
         printresult = result['Data'] [i], end=""
```

The output value is substituted into the printresult.

If the DataFrame uses this printresult,

Could real-time data input be possible?
Thought.

---

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! this is an interesting question, but there are a lot of open design points here. you seem to be importing JAKMain, but JAKMain just prints the results. How are you establishing a connection to the stream? What do you want to do with the data as it's read in, i.e. do you want an ever-expanding dataframe or do you want to process the data in chunks? Please see the guide [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on providing complete questions.

Comment: "I am well aware that JAKMain.py only outputs results."
"So I changed the code of JAKMain.py as follows."
  print(result['Data'] [i], end="") -> printresult = result['Data'] [i], end=""
"After assigning the output to a variable, I wondered if the DataFrame could receive the variable."

Comment: I want an ever-expanding dataframe.

Comment: can you edit your question rather than responding with code in the comments? and what's stopping you from just appending to a pandas dataframe within JAKMain? But the main question I have is what do you want to happen then? is your ultimate goal writing to a file? or are you hoping to work with the data in a pandas DataFrame live while it's being updated in the background?

Comment: How are you establishing a connection to the stream? <--- I'm asking because I don't know how to do this.

Comment: what's stopping you from just appending to a pandas dataframe within JAKMain? <-- I don't know what you mean. Nothing prevents you from appending to a Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: are you hoping to work with the data in a pandas DataFrame live while it's being updated in the background? <-- We will also work while updating in the background. But before that, I want to input and display it like "my photo" in a Pandas DataFrame.
I think I'll be happy until I get there.

Comment: ok. this is way too big of a project for a stackoverflow question. building a framework that asynchronously updates a pandas DataFrame in place while you're working with it involves threading and a lot of other complex parts with unlimited design considerations that you haven't begun to tackle. I'd start with writing the data to a csv and then reading it in periodically and see if you can work with that.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the data displayed in the Pandas DataFrame changes columns and rows. Data is stacked sideways for uploaded photos. However, It doesn't matter if the data piles down.